# Django-REST-framework Concrete-View-Classes not returning json?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a new app using React and DRF in which React must get the data from DRF in JSON and parse the data. But I think some of my Generic View Classes do not return JSON correctly.

For Example, a "ListCreateAPIView" class returns this:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"5 Storey I=1.3","Value":1399511075,"NSt":5},{"id":6,"name":"5 Storey I=0.7","Value":1344981250,"NSt":5},{"id":7,"name":"5 Storey I=1","Value":1363157800,"NSt":5}]
```

While a "RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView" class returns this:

```
{"id":6,"name":"5 Storey I=0.7","Value":1344981250,"NSt":5,"jRatio":"[0.2,0.4,0.4]","jEDR":"[0.02,0.1,0.5,1]","jStrDrSL":"[0.3826667,0.6046667,0.78,0.8666667]","StrDrB":0.8,"jNStrDrSL":"[0.4,0.8,2.5,5]","NStrDrB":0.75,"jNStrAccSL":"[0.25,0.5,1,2]","NStrAccB":0.5,"jPGA":"[0.141,0.374,0.550,0.822]","jRePr":"[75,475,975,2475]","NNTH":7,"jP_CL":"[ 0 , 5 , 6 , 7 ]","jMIDR":"[[[0.014488,0.021893,0.010635,0.029521,0.009106,0.013556,0.034016], [0.019524,0.022306,0.013733,0.041172,0.012122,0.019027,0.027467], \r\n[0.018057,0.019549,0.01485,0.034628,0.010172,0.022447,0.02065], \r\n[0.018057,0.015954,0.009193,0.024401,0.006838,0.022809,0.017592], \r\n[0.017192,0.012215,0.009257,0.016268,0.005854,0.019945,0.012777]], \r\n\r\n[[0.016604,0.025492], \r\n[0.026047,0.03113], \r\n[0.02794,0.02432], \r\n[0.024571,0.01748], \r\n[0.023962,0.014474]], \r\n\r\n[[0.040325], \r\n[0.044064], \r\n[0.035164], \r\n[0.024971], \r\n[0.020532]], \r\n\r\n[[1], \r\n[1], \r\n[1], \r\n[1], \r\n[1]]]","jMAcc":"[[[0.081014271,0.126595311,0.094557594,0.094250765,0.068444444,0.088719674,0.118411825], \r\n[0.06911213,0.091793068,0.097146789,0.11106422,0.056927625,0.118172273,0.103258919], \r\n[0.076614679,0.077261978,0.120961264,0.144769623,0.055780836,0.08214475,0.123833843], \r\n[0.082191641,0.08675739,0.129832824,0.13788685,0.04724159,0.071845056,0.091466871], \r\n[0.18904791,0.111108053,0.098691131,0.13933945,0.052319062,0.198410805,0.117994903]], \r\n\r\n[[0.184002039,0.156264016], \r\n[0.18011213,0.122554536], \r\n[0.24753211,0.136911315], \r\n[0.292653415,0.120941896], \r\n[0.255610601,0.127876656]], \r\n\r\n[[0.201146789], \r\n[0.173687054], \r\n[0.17719368], \r\n[0.172267074], \r\n[0.187479103]], \r\n\r\n[[1], \r\n[1], \r\n[1], \r\n[1], \r\n[1]]]"}
```

Notice that the data doesn't start with a bracket "[" and because of this I'm not able to parse it in React. I need to know where the problem is. Should I not use GenericViewClasses?

views.py:

```
class BuildingsList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class=BuildingSerializerList

class BuildingDetails(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class=BuildingSerializerDetails
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', BuildingsList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', BuildingDetails.as_view()),]
```

serializers.py:

```
class BuildingSerializerList(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Building
        fields=['id','name','Value','NSt']


class BuildingSerializerDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Building
        fields='__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`Detail-View`** means, it only returns **One** item/details of particular **`look-up`**. and moreover, the response behavior will purely depend on your Serializer classes (`BuildingSerializerList` and `BuildingSerializerDetails`).
The `ListCreateAPIView` is meant for `listing` all your `Building` instances.
In terms of `react`, the Detail-view returns a **`JSON object`** whereas in List-view it returns a **`JSON-Array`**
I would recommend you to use [DRF's `ModelViewset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) class for views, which is very handy
**UPDATE-1**
You can do simple CRUD operations on `Sample` model through REST-API by using following view class

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class SampleViewset(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
```

If you are trying to do `CRUD operations` by using **`GenericViewSet`**, you need to write views like this,

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet


class SampleNew(GenericViewSet):
    queryset = SampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your list logic
        return response

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your list logic
        return response

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your list logic
        return response

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your list logic
        return response
```

Did you see the difference !!

Comment: thanks for the answer!  is it not a good practice to use GenericViews for CRUD apps?  aren't they layers of abstraction for ModelViewsets?

Comment: `ModelViewSet` is inherited from `GenericViews`. Apart from that, `ModelViewSet` has more `specific features` that would help you to do **CRUD Operations in few lines of code (least 3 lines)**

Comment: Anyway I updated the answer with lilte more details. (**UPDATE-1** section)

Answer (score 2):

Get `ListCreateAPIView` will return a list(`jsonarray`),get `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` will return a single object info(`jsonobject`) is right,that's `ListCreateAPIView` and `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` designed to be.You would better change the parse code in fontend in React.

In your case is `GenericAPIView` not suit your requirement,I think you want to CRUD the model `Building` by DRF,then the `ModelViewSet` is something you actually needed.

views.py

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class BuildingViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Building.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializerList
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['update', 'partial_update', 'retrieve']:
            return BuildingSerializerDetails
        else:
            return self.serializer_class
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'building', BuildingViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

then

create with post `http://localhost/building/`

list with get `http://localhost/building/` # return jsonarray

detail with get `http://localhost/building/id/` # return jsonobject

update with put/patch `http://localhost/building/id/`

delete with delete `http://localhost/building/id/`

---

If you really want detail return a list,simple change to:

```
class BuildingViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ....
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response([serializer.data])
```

but it's really meaningless.